# sort((a,b) => b-a) in Java

Tags: java

Using .sort without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, ['a', 'b'].sort() results in ['a', 'b'] because a has a lower code point.

Using .sort without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, ['a', 'b'].sort() results in ['a', 'b'] because a has a lower code point.

Using .sort without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, ['a', 'b'].sort() results in ['a', 'b'] because a has a lower code point.

Using .sort without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, ['a', 'b'].sort() results in ['a', 'b'] because a has a lower code point.

Using .sort without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, ['a', 'b'].sort() results in ['a', 'b'] because a has a lower code point.

Comment: Any example data set that you're running?

Answer (score 7):

Using `.sort` without a callback will compare each element lexiograhically. For example, `['a', 'b'].sort()` results in `['a', 'b']` because `a` has a lower code point.

But your provided custom sort callback won't work with strings:

```
.sort((a,b) => b - a )
```

because `-` will try to coerce both operands to a number - but non-numeric strings can't be converted to numbers. You'll get `NaN` returned each time the callback is called, so sorting won't work.

```js
console.log('a' - 'b')
```

If you wanted to compare lexiographically in your custom compare function, you'd need to do something like:

```
.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

instead of using `-`. `-` would only work if all characters of the string are numeric.